# how go get the exact current city name via javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I needd a javascript or jquery code to get current city name. Previously i trie with goggle map but based on the returning string, some time i get sublocation wih in the city, can any one help in this.

Answer (score 3):

Please check following link. I hope it will help for you.

https://coderwall.com/p/ouofjg/getting-current-location-with-javascript